# Использование перевернутого стэка

Tags: python, list, стек

Как я читал,стэк в питоне это лист(предполагаю что так-же и set'ы,и tuple'ы,исправьте если я не прав),который используют с последнего элемента.

Так вот,будет ли считаться стэком лист,который я переверну,и буду тогда использовать не с последнего элемента,а с первого, т.к перевернул его

Comment: это будет очередь похоже, почитайте про LIFO и FIFO

Comment: Из set никак не получится сделать стэк, т.к. set не сохраняет порядок элементов и вообще "схлопывает" одинаковые элементы, а это ломает всю логику стэка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как я читал,стэк в питоне это лист(предполагаю что так-же и set'ы,и
>   tuple'ы,исправьте если я не прав),который используют с последнего
>   элемента.

Стэк в любом языке - это абстрактный тип данных, представляющий собой список элементов, организованных по принципу [LIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO). Что именно используется на более низком уровне абстракции для хранения данных - не важно, если этот контейнер способен обеспечивать упорядоченное добавление и удаление элементов. Что, кстати, исключает использование множеств (set) и кортежей (tuple), так как первые не обеспечивают упорядоченности, а вторые неизменяемы.

> Так вот,будет ли считаться стэком лист,который я переверну,и буду
>   тогда использовать не с последнего элемента,а с первого, т.к
>   перевернул его

Смотря в какой момент произойдёт "переворачивание". Если добавление и удаление всегда будет проходить с одного конца, то неважно какой именно это конец. Верхушка стека - это тоже абстракция. А если добавлять с одного конца, а удалять с другого, то это нарушает принцип "последним пришёл — первым вышел" и превращает стэк в очередь.